# What is a good collection to use for a set of large data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am trying to serialize data to json so I can send it to a web service.  The List Collection worked well until I got over couple ten thousand rows.  What is a good collection to use to convert to json so I have the format that I desire and won't run out of memory if the data gets too large?

```
[
   Items:
    {  name: "name", type: "type" } 
]
```

Comment: Does it need to be a collection? Can't you write a class and just serialize it directly?

Comment: Its not wise to send all the data to client in one go as web browser will take long to download and no one is going to view ten thousand records in one page. `You should use pagination or auto load the next record when use scrolls down the page`.

Comment: Pushing 10s of thousands of rows out as JSON to be given to a browser is going to be nasty no matter how you slice it. You really need to implement some pagination so the browser isn't having to handle so much data in a single go. Assuming you're pulling from a database this will also cut down on the size of your collection.

Comment: The appropriate data structure is entirely based on how you plan to use the data.  Will you be adding to just the end, the start, arbitrary locations?  Will you be searching at indexes, at the start, end, finding values?  Will you be removing from the start, end, at arbitrary locations, or for arbitrary values?  Does it need to be ordered?  And of course, this is just to get started.

Comment: I would not agree this when sending the data to a web service as this means more calls. From what I gather this data isn't being sent to a user to view in a browser.

Comment: I do understand this, but I don't think it addresses my issue.  I understand pagination would do it, but I am trying to find out if if there is a collection that would hold this.

Comment: Is there a better method to convert it to json aside from converting it to collection of course.  I know I can paginate, but I am trying to find some alternate solution.  Thanks.  The load will be probably run once or twice most.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your data doesn't need to be in JSON format in order to send it to a Web service.

Second, the type of collection doesn't really matter. If it's a `List` or `array` or other, it gets serialized in more or less the same way.

Third, do you absolutely require to send thousands of rows in a single call? You might as well call your service multiple times with manageable data chunks.

Finally, if you really need to send such large chunks of data, you may consider ZIPping the data instead of sending it in pure serialized form.

Good luck!

Comment: I would like to do that, but the web service is designed to accept information via json.  This also seems like the most valid solution for this question currently. Thanks.